# Adding minutes to a javascript Date in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime, time

I'm having trouble adding minutes to a date in javascript in Node.js. I have a date object, `bt_time = new Date()`

```
bt_time.toString()
"Mon Mar 07 2016 03:30:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
```

The following operations attempting to add 5 minutes to the give the following results

```
bt_time + (60*1000*5)
"Mon Mar 07 2016 03:30:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)300000"

new Date(bt_time + (60*1000*5)).toString()
"Mon Mar 07 2016 03:30:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

new Date(bt_time) + (60*1000*5)
"Mon Mar 07 2016 03:30:10 GMT+0000 (UTC)300000"
```

It seems like the + (60*1000*5) is just tacking 300000 at the end of the date string, instead of adding to the time. I don't have the same issue when I attempt subtraction.

I need the date arithmetic to be able to iterate spans of days, 5 minutes at a time.

Comment: How about `bt_time.setMinutes(bt_time.getMinutes() + 5);`

Comment: @Pointy, will that be able to advance the date to the next hour, at the top of the hour? Or advance to the next day beyond 23:59

Comment: Yes, it will. Adding to any of the Date fields will result in a proper date reflecting the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re:

> ```
> I don't have the same issue when I attempt subtraction
> ```

because the  [subtraction operator `-`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus) forces it's operands to Number, so:

```
bt_time - (60*1000*5)
```

is effectively:

```
bt_time.getTime() - 300000
```

which will create a number (that represents milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch) with a value 300,000 smaller than the time value of `bt_time`.

#### Already answered, but for completeness:

However, the [addition operator `+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) is overloaded, so in:

```
bt_time + (60*1000*5)
```

the script engine has to work out whether it means [addition, concatenation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-addition-operator-plus) or coercion to a number ([+ unary operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator)). By default, a Date object coerces to string, so `+` acts as a concatenation operator and as Daishi Nakajima says, is effectively:

```
bt_time.toString() +  300000
```

Answer (score 3):

bt_time is `object` type. `bt_time + i` means `bt_time.toString() + i`

correct is

```
new Date(bt_time.getTime() + 60*1000*5).toString();
// or
bt_time.setMinutes(bt_time.getMinutes() + 5);
```

I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in nodejs

```
moment().add(5, 'minutes').toDate();
```